Example of an aspherical non-manifold Alexandrov 3-space
Let us call a CW Alexandrov space $X$ aspherical if $X$ is the classifying space of its fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$. Can someone give me an example of a closed, aspherical Alexandrov space that is not a topological manifold?
I know that obtaining examples of closed non-manifold Alexandrov spaces is itself not so easy. So I'd be happy to look at such an aspherical example in the smallest possible dimension $3$.

A survey on 3d Alexandrov spaces can be found at https://durham-repository.worktribe.com/output/1620966, and on p.20 it is conjectured that every closed aspherical 3d Alexandrov space is homeomorphic to a 3-manifold.

One potential source of examples would be orbifolds. Say, take a closed Riemannian manifold of dimension $>2$ (e.g. a hyperbolic one), and take a quotient by a finite isometry group that has fixed points. The quotient is an Alexandrov space and you need to find an example where the underlying space of the orbifold is aspherical (which may be hard) and also a closed manifold.

@IgorBelegradek I myself have been trying to use orbifolds but haven't gotten aspherical examples yet. The conjecture that you mentioned reinforces my belief that such examples (if they exist) could be very hard to find!

I would start by studying the rich class of flat and hyperbolic closed orbifolds. Are their underlying spaces always non-aspherical (or else homeomorphic to manifolds)? I find this hard to believe.

@IgorBelegradek: can you give a reference for the statement that “the quotient is an Alexandrov space”? It’s already quite subtle to describe the natural metric on the quotient.

@HJRW: the lower curvature bound passes to quotients of isometric group actions (with closed orbits to make sure the quotient is a metric space). A reference e.g. Corollary 8.34 on p.95 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08539.
